# Fetch hook and NuxtLoading component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a question about migration from `asyncData` pattern to `fecth` in Nuxt App. It seems straightforward, except for 1 thing - i can't get NuxtLoading component to act right. I've tried to watch for `$fetchState` and start loading with `this.$nuxt.$loading.start()`, but it's no use. The loading indicator flashes for mere second and disappears without any input on my part.
Is there a trick to make it work like it does with `asyncData`?

Comment: On top of my answer, you could maybe share us a [repro] or some code to see what may not work properly here.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using `fetch()` is to not block the render in between pages. The loader is here to let the user know when he will be able to expect the next page.

When you're using `fetch()`, you can use `$fetchState.pending` to make a conditional and display either a loader or a skeleton like this: https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton/

The loading bar should still be triggered but it will probably be smoother (and maybe shorter visually), I'd recommend to let it live it's life.